# Why git bash dont install npm packages

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash

This week I cannot install any npm packages. Only show this error:

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/nookies

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Feruz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-03T15_34_55_561Z-debug-0.log
```

I use [v2rayN](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayN) vpn. This vpn work at browser well. But on git bash terminal dont work.

Comment: What is the content of  `C:\Users\Feruz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-03T15_34_55_561Z-debug-0.log`? Any important informations?

Comment: I dont know only this error show. I think npm cache. When I run npm i nookies then get this error